# how can i adjust the rows and move it to the right side

Tags: java

Bus Seat Reservation:

```
        Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Row 0   |
*       *       *       *       Row 1   |
*       *       *       *       Row 2   |
*       *       *       *       Row 3   |
*       *       *       *       Row 4   |
*       *       *       *       Row 5   |
*       *       *       *       Row 6   |
*       *       *       *       Row 7   |
*       *       *       *       Row 8   |
*       *       *       *       Row 9   |
*       *       *       *
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class SeatReservation{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        char[][] upuan = new char[10][4];

        for (int a = 0; a < upuan.length; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b < upuan[a].length; b++){
                upuan[a][b] = '*';
            }
        }
        while (true){
        System.out.println("Bus Seat Reservation:");
        System.out.println("\t\tCol1\tCol2\tCol3\tCol4");
        for (int a = 0; a < upuan.length; a++){
            System.out.println("Row " + a + "\t|");
            for (int b = 0; b < upuan[a].length; b++){
                System.out.print(upuan[a][b] + "\t\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();


        System.out.print("Enter row and colum to reserve separated by space (Enter a negative number to exit): ");
        String input = sc.nextLine();

        if(input.contains("-")){
            System.out.println("Program Exit");
            break;
        }


        int row = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(0));
        int column = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(2));

        upuan[row][column] = 'X';
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print the first “Row...” you’re using `println()`. This will print the row and then introduce a line break.

Try using a `print()` for the row and then using a `println()` after the for loop.